# Centralizer of Sylow $p$-subgroups for nonabelian finite simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Given a nonabelian finite simple group $G$, is it always true that 
$$C_G(P)\leq P$$
for each Sylow $p$-subgroup $P\leq G$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, $P=\langle (12345)\rangle$ is a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G=A_8$ but $(678)\in C_G(P)$.

Answer (score 4):

For simple groups of lie type is true. This is Lemma 4 of M.R. Darafshe, *Groups with the same non-commuting graph*, Discrete Applied Mathematics, **157** (2009), pp. 833-837 doi: [10.1016/j.dam.2008.06.010](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2008.06.010).

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes here. This answer is a useful and interesting addition, addressing a special case. I have made the reference more clear, and it is to a proper journal article.

Comment: The answer was edited.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Yes, by me. As I said above, this was to simply make the reference more clear.